# How do I stop AJAX query?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I've taken my first real step into AJAX and I'm using the following call that works fine:

```
function mapSuppliers(customer_id) {
    $.get("get.map.points.php", { c_id: customer_id },
     function(data){
         if (data!='') {
            openMapWindow(data);
         } else {
             alert("Missing map coordinates - cannot display map");
         }
     });

}
```

My Question - Using Firebug to monitor the process, it makes the call and returns the values as expected.  However, the little loading circle that indicates activity continues to spin long after data is returned.

Do I need to close the connection or stop the call? WHy does the circle keep spinning?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Check this behavior in Chrome also to confirm whether this if Firebug issue.
2. Is this a PHP application and are you using [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) or [ob_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)?

Answer (score 0):

```
     function(data){
         $("#myimage").hide();
         if (data!='') {
            openMapWindow(data);
         } else {
             alert("Missing map coordinates - cannot display map");
         }
     });
```

Just hide image in callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the spinning image once ajax call is completed. Alternatively you can use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` methods that will be used for all ajax requests.

E.g.

```
$("#imageID").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
});

$("#imageID").ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```